# Angular 14 with Storybook 6.5.13 - decorators and preview-head.html doesn't work

Tags: angular, decorator, storybook, angular-storybook

We are upgrading Angular to the newest version - 14 and we have problem with storybook. After few tries to launch storybook after upgrading angular i decided to remove all storybook configuration files and install it again (v6.5.13). after that i had to rewrite all stories because knobs are deprecated and i had to use controls. This is not a problem, problem is that i can't import external decorator to the story with success, and the preview-head.html doesn't work.
i have only one clue from console:
`applyDecorators was not supported :( !`
Here is some code:
preview.ts

```
import docJson from "../documentation.json";
setCompodocJson(docJson);

export const parameters = {
  actions: { argTypesRegex: "^on[A-Z].*" },
  controls: {
    matchers: {
      color: /(background|color)$/i,
      date: /Date$/,
    },
  },
  docs: { inlineStories: true },
};
```

preview-head.html:

```
<script src="https://hammerjs.github.io/dist/hammer.min.js"></script>

<script>
  (function () {
    window.onload = function () {
      // Added custom class to body tag in storybook isolated context.
      document.body.classList.add("xyz", "mat-typography");
    };
  })();
</script>
```

external decorator:

```
import { SharedModule } from "@app/shared";
import { CoreModule } from "@app/core";
import { RouterTestingModule } from "@angular/router/testing";
import { AuthService } from "@app/core/services/auth.service";
import { AuthMockService } from "@app/core/services/auth.mock.service";
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from "@angular/platform-browser/animations";
import { ApiService } from "@app/core/services/api.service";
import { ApiMockService } from "@app/core/services/api.mock.service";
import { UserMockService } from "@app/core/services/user.mock.service";
import { UserService } from "@app/core/services/user.service";
import { BrowserModule } from "@angular/platform-browser";
import { DialogHelperComponent } from "./dialog-helper.component";
import { CartService } from "@app/core/services/cart.service";
import MOCKED_CART_DATA from "@app/core/mocks/cart-data.mock";
import { MetaModule, MetaConfig } from "ng2-meta";

const defaultMetaData: MetaConfig = {
  useTitleSuffix: true,
  warnMissingGuard: false,
  defaults: {
    title: "xyz 2",
    "any:other": "arbitrary tag can be used",
    author: "@xyz",
    description: "xyz application",
  },
};

/**
 * This module imports all necessary elements for stories and mocks services.
 * Use this module only in stories for storybook.
 */
@NgModule({
  declarations: [DialogHelperComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    SharedModule,
    CoreModule,
    RouterTestingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MetaModule.forRoot(defaultMetaData),
  ],
  providers: [
    { provide: ApiService, useClass: ApiMockService },
    { provide: AuthService, useClass: AuthMockService },
    { provide: UserService, useClass: UserMockService },
  ],
  exports: [
    SharedModule,
    CoreModule,
    RouterTestingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    DialogHelperComponent,
    MetaModule,
  ],
})
export class StorybookModule {
  constructor(private _cart: CartService) {
    console.warn(
      "Storybook module imported. This module should be used only by storybook isolate module!"
    );
    /**
     * Initialize cart mock in cart service for cart sub-views.
     */
    this._cart.setCartData(MOCKED_CART_DATA, "fake-id");
  }
}
```

and stories sample:

```
import { StorybookModule } from "stories/storybook.module";
import DIALOG_TYPE from "@app/core/constants/dialogs-type";
import { MatDialogModule } from "@angular/material/dialog";
import { action } from "@storybook/addon-actions";
import { DuplicateCartComponent } from "./duplicate-cart.component";
import { Story } from "@storybook/angular/types-6-0";
import { Meta, moduleMetadata } from "@storybook/angular";

const notes = `
#Duplicate cart dialog
## Description

Component for display duplication cart dialog.

###[documentation](${COMPODOC_BASE_URL}/components/DuplicateCartComponent.html)
`;

export default {
  title: "shared/Dialogs Components/Duplicate cart dialog",
  component: DuplicateCartComponent,
  parameters: {
    notes,
  },
  decorators: [moduleMetadata({ imports: [StorybookModule, MatDialogModule] })],
} as Meta;

const Template: Story<DuplicateCartComponent> = (args) => ({
  props: { ...args, close: action("close") },
  template: `
         <xyz-dialog-helper
         [dialogType]="dialogType"
         [dialogData]="dialogData"
         (closeDialog)="close($event)"></xyz-dialog-helper>
       `,
});

export const Default = Template.bind({});
Default.args = {
  dialogType: DIALOG_TYPE.DUPLICATE_CART,
  dialogData: {},
};
```

as i said at the begining i had angular 14 and storybook 6.5.13. before the migration to 14, we used angular 11 and the decorator and preview-head.html file were the same, and all work.
Can You help me with decorator import and preview-head.html?